# Sentences without a pos - Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tokenize

I have tokenized the text and want to print error for the sentences without a pos but it prints error for every single sentence. How should I change it?

```py
sents = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)

for sent in sents:
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sent)
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
    
    for pos in tagged:        
        if 'VB' not in sents :
             print('error')
```

Comment: @jsids, You need to say `if 'VB' not in pos:`, I think. Right now you check the variable `sents` that you define at the top of the file every time your `if` statement runs.

Answer (score 0):

As @baileythegreen pointed out, thought your last condition is only after tagging the sents, `if 'VB' not in sents:` is checking the entire tokenized text.
which returns true for every iteration even if the sent you're iterating over has a 'VB' tag in it.
you probably should use a flag E.g. has_VB = False and the condition should be`if 'VB' not in tagged[1]: has_VB = True`
and after the for loop is finished `if  has_VB: print(error)`

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "this sentence has verb. this one not"
sents = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)

for sent in sents:
    has_verb = False
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sent)
    pos_tags = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
    for pos_tag in pos_tags:        
        if 'VB' in pos_tag[1] :
            has_verb=True
            break
    if not has_verb:
        print(f'error: "{sent}" does not have verb')
```